# JTextField que al pasarlos a otra clase me llegan vacíos

Tags: java-swing, jtextfield

Cuando pulso en el botón no recibo ningún error, ni me recoge el dato escrito en el *JTextField* ni me imprime por consola *null* solo una cadena vacía sin nada de texto.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Princi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Marco m=new Marco();
        
        Lamin lm=new Lamin();
    
        m.add(lm);
        
        m.setVisible(true);
    
        m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}


class Marco extends JFrame{
    
    public Marco() {
    
    JFrame fr=new JFrame();
    
    setBounds(200,200,300,300);
    
    }
}



class Lamin extends JPanel{
    
    JTextField text=new JTextField(10);
    
    JButton a=new JButton("Boton");
    
    public Lamin() {
        
        add(text);
        
        a.addActionListener(oyente);
        
        add(a);  
        
    }
    
    
    public String getTexto() {
        
    return text.getText();
    
    }


Lamina oyente=new Lamina(); 
    
}

class Lamina implements ActionListener{
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        Lamin lm1=new Lamin();

        System.out.println(lm1.getTexto());
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es la siguiente clase (Lee los comentarios):

```
class Lamina implements ActionListener{
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // CREAS UN NUEVO OBJETO DEL TIPO Lamin.
        // Este Objeto no hace referencia al objeto Lamin originalmente instanciado.
        Lamin lm1=new Lamin();

        System.out.println(lm1.getTexto());
    }
}
```

Debes cambiar esa clase a algo como esto:

```
class Lamina implements ActionListener {

    private Lamin lm1;

    // creamos un constructor donde inyectamos la referencia del Objeto Lamin Original.
    Lamina(Lamin lm1) {
        this.lm1 = lm1;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(lm1.getTexto());
    }
}
```

Y cuando instancies un objeto de la Clase Lamina debes pasarle la instancia del objeto del tipo Lamin:
 (Lee los Comentrios)

```
class Lamin extends JPanel {

    JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
    JButton a = new JButton("Boton");

    public Lamin() {
        add(text);
        a.addActionListener(oyente);
        add(a);
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return text.getText();
    }
    // Acá instanciamos un objeto del tipo Lamina
    // El constructor nos pide un Objeto del tipo Lamin.
    // Entonces le inyectamos el mismo objeto de donde partimos (this) -"este"
    Lamina oyente = new Lamina(this);
}
```

Finalmente tú código quedaría:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Princi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marco m = new Marco();
        Lamin lm = new Lamin();
        m.add(lm);
        m.setVisible(true);
        m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class Marco extends JFrame {

    public Marco() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        setBounds(200, 200, 300, 300);
    }
}

class Lamin extends JPanel {

    JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
    JButton a = new JButton("Boton");

    public Lamin() {
        add(text);
        a.addActionListener(oyente);
        add(a);
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return text.getText();
    }

    // Acá instanciamos un objeto del tipo Lamina
    // El constructor nos pide un Objeto del tipo Lamin.
    // Entonces le inyectamos el mismo objeto de donde partimos (this) -"este"
    Lamina oyente = new Lamina(this);
}

class Lamina implements ActionListener {

    private Lamin lm1;

    // creamos un constructor donde inyectamos la referencia del Objeto Lamin Original.
    Lamina(Lamin lm1) {
        this.lm1 = lm1;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(lm1.getTexto());
    }
}
```